# Как go импортирует пакеты, если имя каталога не совпадает с именем пакета

Tags: golang, импорт

У меня есть пакет translater (он же каталог), в  котором есть два утильных субпакета, которые импортируются по имени translater/пакет и главный main файл translater.go  (он же package main - да, я его не переименовал в main.go, но это не важно).

Затем мне захотелось поэкспериментировать и сделать вторую версию пакета.
Я скопировал все содержимое в каталога translater2. Сделал новую версию translater.go,  скомпилировал. Все работает. Затем захотел создать третью версию пакета. Скопировал все в каталог translater3. Опять все компилируется. Затем решил сделать так: translater3\v3. Опять все компилируется.

Вопрос: а  как go находит субпакеты, если имя стартового каталога не совпадает с именем в импортах? Везде же написано, что импорт в go основан на структуре каталогов?
Я сначала подумал, что go импортирует субпакеты из старого расположения translater\*. Я переименовал его в *translater0*. Все по-прежнему работает.

Вот импорт моих субпакетов, которые в translater.go остаются неизменными.

```
"translater/mysqlconnect"
"translater/utils"
"translater/yapi"
```

Ну и сопутствующий вопрос: а  как вообще правильно делать версионирование своих пакетов?

Comment: Почитайте [про модули](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#quick-start).  Особенно [про публикацию второй мажорной версии](https://blog.golang.org/v2-go-modules).

Comment: Я читал. Где там ответ на мой первый вопрос? У меня используется go mod.

Answer (score 0):

Надо понимать, что имя каталога и имя пакета не одно и тоже. Попробуйте в одном пакете разместить несколько файлов с разной пакетной принадлежностью. Компилятор выдаст ошибку. Т.е. попросту говоря -- вы указываете путь импорта, а не имя пакета для импорта.

Comment: "имя каталога и имя пакета не одно и тоже."  Это я понимаю. Пакет это файл либо совокупность файлов под одной директивой package name.  Но тогда что означает для компилятора строка: import "translater/utils" ? Если учесть, что  части пути (translater как каталога в котором находится файл translater.go) не существует, но все компилируется.  И почему везде пишут что пакеты в Go основаны на структуре каталогов. И имена пакетов должны совпадать с именами каталогов. В спецификации языка я ничего не нашел, чтобы  могло бы развеять мое непонимание.

Comment: Как Go понимает что такое utils и где он находится?

Comment: В общем пока я понял одну штуку: когда мы используем go mod init, то есть создаем собственный модуль с каким-то именем, то Go становится плевать на файловые пути. Он использует имя  модуля как часть пути импорта субпакета ( видимо, просто подменяя имя модуля на текущий каталог) и ему неважно, что это имя не совпадает с именем текущего каталога.

Comment: Вы указываете путь -- откуда импортировать. Последняя часть пути -- становится именем для обращении. А пакет внутри пути -- может иметь другое имя. Но работать вы будете именно с последним именем в импорте.
"utils" -- это пакет, "ендпоинт". Именно с ним будет работать парсер golang.
Если вы работаете с модулем -- то там отделньая песня. Да, будет обращении именно к имени модуля, ещё и с указанием версии (именно из-за различных версий модули и были придуманы).

Comment: Хотя "модуль", имхо -- в данном случае -- название, которое вводит в заблуждение. То, что директория и имя пакета должны совпадать -- это принцип наименьшего удивления; рекомендация, а не закон.